# python make a sql insert inside for loop going through a sql query

Tags: python, for-loop

i'm going through a sql table and making an sql insert inside the for loop.
After the first insert , Python does not seem to continue with the next line, but throws me an
duplicate key constraint error.

```py
query = ("SELECT id, lang, desc, name FROM tablex )
data = cursor.execute(query)
for i in data:

    if (i[1])==2:
        print ("translation present")
        
    else:
        if (i[2])!="":
            oevar = str(i[2])
            result = translator.translate_text(text=oevar,target_lang="EN-US")  
            tldesc =str(result)
            tltitle = str(i[3]) #title untranslated
            tlid = (i[0])
            cursor.execute("""insert into tablex
                (id, lang, Plattform, Shop,cName, desc)
                values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (tlid, 2, 1, 0,tltitle,tldesc))
            cnxn.commit()
```

Now the first row will be added to the table,
then giving me the key constraint error for the same id i just added.
somehow the cursor seems to be stuck after that insert statement

Comment: `tlid` is the same id you just read from the table, so of course that id already exists...

Comment: well ok, but this id may exist several times. what changes is the lang code.
there are already sever ebtry in the db with the same "id"
Its actually an item number, not an real id in this sense. I'm trying using a second cursor right now, as it looks to me the 2nd call for the execution of the cursor messes with my loop

Comment: It would help a lot if you showed us the actual error.  Otherwise we are just guessing  what the unique constraint is.

Comment: Also, the lang code does _not_ change (assuming you mean the `lang` column), because you are inserting the fixed value `2` every time for that column.

Comment: @john-gordon true - sorry for that. (parts of the error came in german language, so I was unsure of how helpful this might be.) Thanks for your help, its appreciated!